# Can I use table name and alias name both interchangeably in sql joins

Tags: sql, mysql, join

If I have query

```
SELECT FNAME, CNAME 
FROM FACULTY F, COURSES C 
WHERE F.FID=C.FID 
  AND COURSES.FID='F04';
```

so can i use `COURSES.FID` or once alias is there I should use only that.

though I am getting error if I am using table name instead of alias. Is it expected output?

Comment: Each table copy have only one alias. When you specify an alias in `COURSES [AS] C` then the original table name is overrided in the tables list, and it cannot be used. Alias is assigned == alias must be used always.

Comment: 1) Do not use old "comma-style JOIN", use explicit join. 2) When the datasource includes more than one source (table and/or local variables namespace) then add table alias to EACH column name - i.e. the columns in the output list must be aliased too.

Comment: The error message provides you with the answer, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

yes, it doesn't conflict with any other aliases, you can use any aliases.

```
SELECT F.FNAME, C.CNAME  FROM FACULTY F, COURSES C WHERE F.FID=C.FID AND C.FID='F04';
```

but in your query, you should refer to columns from the COURSES table using the alias C. For this reason, in your query, you should use C.FID rather than COURSES.FID.

Answer (score 0):

Any of the both AliasName.ColName or TableName.ColName can be used. No change in the result or performance.